# QGIS "ERROR 6: No translation for Lambert_Conformal_Conic to PROJ.4 format is known."

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, clip

I am trying to clip a county DEM file using the PLSS Section shape files as mask layers... that is, I want it clipped to sections so that I can load my DEM into QGIS one section at a time, without having to load the whole 4GB raster for any little project I want to work on.

I have tried to do this by going to **Raster > Extraction > Clipper** ... however it returns an error:

> ERROR 6: No translation for Lambert_Conformal_Conic to PROJ.4 format
>   is known. ERROR 6: No translation for Lambert_Conformal_Conic to
>   PROJ.4 format is known.

I have found a way to rasterize the shape files and use the raster calculator, however this is more of a pain and I want to understand why this is not working for me.

I assume it has something to do with the fact that I'm using a custom CRS for my county? CRS databases don't recognize it.

> +proj=lcc +lat_1=43.57503293972223 +lat_0=43.57503293972223 +lon_0=-90.78333333333333 +k_0=1.0000408158 +x_0=222504.44500889 +y_0=47532.0603505207 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs

Running QGIS 2.0.1 on Macbook Air using Mavericks 10.9

---

I ran **gdalsrsinfo** on the raster file and the command line returned the same error, plus the WKT:

```
ERROR 6: No translation for Lambert_Conformal_Conic to PROJ.4 format is known.
PROJ.4 : ''

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["NAD_1983_HARN_WISCRS_Vernon_County_Feet",
    GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983_HARN",
        DATUM["D_North_American_1983_HARN",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",730000.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",155944.768],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-90.78333333333333],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",43.57503293972223],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0000408158],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",43.57503293972223],
    UNIT["Foot_US",0.30480060960121924],
    VERTCS["NAVD_1988",
        VDATUM["North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988"],
        PARAMETER["Vertical_Shift",0.0],
        PARAMETER["Direction",1.0],
        UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a known bug in GDAL working in the background of QGIS about different ways of definition for LCC 1-SP and 2-SP projections:

See

- https://github.com/mapbox/node-srs/issues/1
- http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2011-May/028728.html
- http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/2072

Adding `ESRI::` in a gdalwarp command line as described should solve the problem. Or change the shapefiles .prj to

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_HARN_WISCRS_Vernon_County_Feet",
GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983_HARN",
    DATUM["D_North_American_1983_HARN",
            SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",43.57503293972223],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-90.78333333333333],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1.0000408158],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",730000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",155944.768],
    UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]]
```

and run `gdal_translate -a_srs new.prj src_dataset dst_dataset` on the raster file.

Note that false Easting and Northing are in feet for the .prj file, and always in meters for the +proj string.

---

**UPDATE**

I found the DEM at http://relief.ersc.wisc.edu/wisconsinview/form.php and PLSS data at http://www.geocommunicator.gov/GeoComm/lsis_home/home/PLSS_download_WIcounty.htm (in NAD 83)

The PLSS is also imprinted on USGS Topo maps. So I took one township (T13N R02W), and reprojected the shapefile to Vernon WCCS with the parameters given above. The DEM comes in adf format, so I translated that to Vernon WCCS as well:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs "+proj=lcc +lat_1=43.57503293972223 +lat_0=43.57503293972223 +lon_0=-90.78333333333333 +k_0=1.0000408158 +x_0=222504.44500889 +y_0=47532.0603505207 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs" -of GTiff D:/Karten/shp/Laender/USA/vernon/w001000.adf D:/Karten/shp/Laender/USA/Vernon-DEM.tif

gdalwarp -q -cutline D:/Karten/shp/Laender/USA/T13NR02W.shp -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff D:/Karten/shp/Laender/USA/Vernon-DEM.tif D:/Karten/shp/Laender/USA/Vernon-DEM-clipped.tif
```

These are actually the command lines generated by QGIS. The result fits to the township extent:

[image]

Background is the La Farge Topo from 1965.

Comment: Thanks for your help AndreJ. I am still learning the ropes with QGIS, I have only dabbled in the command line side of things.

I updated the shapefile's .prj as you suggested, but the problem did not resolve.

Then I tried running **gdalwarp** in terminal, with **ESRI::** prepended to the filename as suggested, and it is not returning errors but it does not seem to be producing any output. I tried:

`gdalwarp -q -cutline ESRI::"/Users/shapefile.shp" -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff "/Users/demraster.tif" /Users/output`

Comment: For the shapefile, you have to delete the .qpj file QGIS creates. Otherwise it will not look into the exchanged .prj file. You have to run gdal_translate on the raster file to change from lcc to lcc_1SP (which seems to be the problem). Can you give download links to the data? I have not found the shapefiles you mention. I guess the DEM is from http://www.sco.wisc.edu/news/lidar-elevation-data-now-available-on-wisconsinview.html

Comment: Thanks again, I will give that a try. DEM is a 1M LiDAR raster from [WisconsinView](http://relief.ersc.wisc.edu/wisconsinview/form.php)… Vernon County is the one.

I got the PLSS Sections from a buddy of mine who is a GIS professional. Not sure of the sourcing, it is a simple polygon shape file for our county. I can try to upload it somewhere if you want to have a look at it

Comment: Am I right in thinking this would be accomplished by `gdal_translate -a_srs "SRS" source.tif output.tif`??
what should I substitute for `"SRS"` to get LCC 1SP as my output?

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! Worked like a charm. I have been trying to figure this one out for so long, you have no idea how much I appreciate all of your effort!

Comment: I added your case to the GDAL ticket hoping it can be solved.

Comment: Should be fiexd according to https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/2072 in GDAL 2.0.0

Comment: @AndreJ Thanks for all your help. I'd like to accept your answer but I can't find the check mark (which should be under the voting arrows at left…?) Maybe the mods can give some advice here?

Comment: It seems you have two accounts now: https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/43618/corvus and https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/54931/corvus. If you merge them to the first one, you can accept the answer. If you can't remember the password used originally, you can ask for a new one.